# Pandas groupby and append the original values. Count the mean of per row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe of `ID`s and `Value`s. Where `ID`s are kind of repetition of trial and `Value`s are the results. 
I want to do `groupby` by `ID` and for same IDs the `Values` will be added to adjacent columns. Finally I want to calculate the mean of each of the rows.

```py
>>>df
   ID  Value
0   1    1.1
1   2    1.2
2   3    2.4
3   1    1.7
4   2    4.3
5   3    2.2
>>>groups = df.groupby(by='ID')

#Now I cannot figure it what to do for my desired output.
```

I want the output like

```py
   ID  Value_1  Value_2  Mean
0   1    1.1    1.7    1.9
1   2    1.2    4.3    2.75
2   3    2.4    2.2    2.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for new column created by counter per groups by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), reshape by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), change columns names by [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html), add new column filled by means and last data cleaning - [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = (df.assign(g = df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1))
        .pivot('ID','g','Value')
        .add_prefix('Value_')
        .assign(Mean = lambda x: x.mean(axis=1))
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
   ID  Value_1  Value_2  Mean
0   1      1.1      1.7  1.40
1   2      1.2      4.3  2.75
2   3      2.4      2.2  2.30
```

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions, assuming that you have 2 rows for each *ID*:

Define a function to be applied to groups:

```
def fn(grp):
    vals = grp.Value.values
    return [ vals[0], vals[-1], grp.Value.mean() ]
```

Then apply it and "move" *ID* column from index to regular column:

```
df2 = df.groupby('ID').apply(fn).apply(pd.Series).reset_index()
```

And the last point is to set proper column names:

```
df2.columns=[ 'ID', 'Value_1', 'Value_2', 'Mean' ]
```